# How can I display a 5 bit binary as decimal?

Tags: circuit-design

I need help with hexadecimal to decimal conversion for a 5-bit number.
[The task](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498801/how-can-i-make-a-5-bit-binary-display-hex2dec-sheet#comment1272323_498801):

> Create a hex2dec converter for a 5 digit number, using mux and adders. Each digit will be displayed on a 7 segment display.

I can only do it for a 4 bit, since I'm using a 4-bit binary adder.
Please help me to do it for 5 bits, here my truth table

[image: truthtable]

Comment: Hi Asaf, this is a question and answer site. You haven't asked a technical question, yet! Please edit your post to ask a precise question, and explain why you can do it for 4, but not for 5 bits.

Comment: how is it now? ok?

Comment: Add in your truth table. You can type it in and use the `{}` code formatting button to use a fixed width font or add at least four spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: sorry i dont have

Comment: @AsafBenShabat well, then that's your first task, obviously!

Comment: added a truth table . please help me !

Comment: Why are you using an adder to convert hex to decimal?

Comment: i have been asked to

Comment: Can you post the exact words of the question? What you have written doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: create a hex2dec converter for a 5 digit number , using mux and adders , each digit will be displayed on a 7 segment display

Answer (score -1):

Note that the least significant bit *e* plays no role:
It appears unchanged as the least significant bit for the least significant digit.
It has no influence on any other part of the output.

The values come from the first four decades.
Designating the (significant) inputs *a, b, c, d*, the *≥20 bit* is simple enough:
\$y_{20} = ab \lor ac = a(b \lor c)\$; *≥30* is \$y_{30} = abcd\$, but just one reason \$y_{10}\$ should be true:
\$\begin {aligned} y_{10}
 = \neg abc \lor \neg abd & \lor bcd \lor a\neg b\neg c \\
( =\neg ab(c \lor d) &\lor y_{30} \lor a\neg b\neg c)\end {aligned}\$

It is unclear whether the circuit shall use exactly *one* 4-bit adder:
If two are allowed, the somewhat standard solution is the circuit implementation of [double dabble](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble#Parametric_Verilog_implementation_of_the_double_dabble_binary_to_BCD_converter), leaving little use for `using mux`.
A standard multiplexer would need the selection signal encoded as binary:
The \$y_{20} \text{ and }y_{10}\$ above, selecting 0, 3, 6 or 9.
(A four bit adder would re-compute \$y_{10} \text{ and }y_{20}\$ as *highest sum bit* and *carry out* - after an additional delay, inevitably.)

Note that the task reads *for a 5 digit number* which without further qualification likely means *decimal* digits, making for a bigger challenge (14-16 bits in) - it might even be *5 hex digits*.
Use of multiplexers here is anybody's guess, while I can see it in a sequential implementation, I'd prefer shift registers there.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm sure after almost 3 years, OP has either passed or failed the class by now!

Comment: @GlenYates The objective here is to build a Q&A bank. It doesn't matter if OP is no longer here (currently he hasn't been seen for a year) as long as the question is well-formed and can attract quality answers.

Comment: (Down-voters please comment *why* an answer is *not useful*.)

Comment: As to the down-voters, I can see a couple of reasons, one would be the statement "the least significant bit e plays no role" is misleading, while it plays no role in F1, it drives the least significant bit of F2. Another reason may be that you didn't provide a solution using a 'mux and adders" as requested. And a 3rd may be because you were not clairvoyant enough to deduce that though OP mentions "5 digit number" a couple of times, they mention "5 bit" three times and provide a 5 bit truth table, so they probably mean 5 bit.

Comment: I still see straw-men defeated: The answer states *the least significant bit e  appears unchanged as the least significant bit for the least significant digit*, it states equations for signals for a mux to select from `0, 3, 6 or 9` (while not spelling out this to be added to *abcd*), and while most of the question (and answer) revolve around *5 bits*, the closing *Note* refers to what the OP [commented when prompted for *exact words*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498801/how-can-i-display-a-5-bit-binary-as-decimal/658833?noredirect=1#comment1272323_498801): *digits* in&out.